# /usr/bin/gnuplot.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cyggd-2.dll: cannot open shared object file

Tags: x11, windows, cygwin, gnuplot

I am trying to run Octave under Windows and to run graphics plotting routine under it. It requires Cygwin and X/Cygwin.

When I trying to run any plotting routine, the following error appears:

```
/usr/bin/gnuplot.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cyggd-2.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the `libgd2` package to provide the missing `cyggd-2.dll`.